# Pentaho Execute SQL Statements variable conversion to null

Tags: sql, pentaho, kettle, pdi, pentaho-spoon

I am using PDI to delete and insert some data from a DB. I have the following issue. I create two variables called START_DATE and END_DATE that are used to select the data that will be deleted from my DB. I am able to get them and run my transformation with no erors in the log file, but when I checked if data was deleted, I find it didn't. I send checked my "DeleteProcedure" step, and it says "Conversion error: null". I have tried different approached to take the variables and pass them as Strings, but I haven't been able to solve this issue. It cannot be a SQL mistake as I tested it with a constant and it works.

Any ideas? I attach some pics. Thanks!

[image: This is how I try to get my variables]

[image: I get my variables correctly]

Comment: Have you tried SQL quotes in your SQL? For example: BETWEEN 'date(${START_DATE})' AND date( '${END_DATE)') ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a documentation of the `Execute SQL script` says:

> Note: When you have an issue, that the SQL is started at the initialization phase of the transformation and not for each row, make sure to **check** the option **"Execute for each row"** (see description below).

In your case it executes during the initialization phase of the transformation that's why it gets `null` values instead of ones from previous step.

Comment: Anyway, you could use the `Delete` step instead. It should be faster when speaking about performance.